# Why ,toggleButton is not performing its task when it is set to false?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-togglebutton

I have some toggle buttons in my app, I am setting the state of toggle buttons as true at the time of it's first run.The problem is, when i am trying to set false (button turning off) it shows that it is changed its state as false but the action to be performed when it is turned off is not executing.And when i click the button again to turn  on and off ,the button will turn on and off again and then the action to be performed when the button is turned off will execute properly.I dont know what is happening at the first time??Can anybody  help me to find out the problem with this code??? Please excuse my language.
Here I am pasting the sample code of this issue

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ToggleButton tb1=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    tb1.setChecked(true);
```

}

```
public  void getStatus(View view)
{

 final  ToggleButton tb1=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
  tb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
 {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
     {
        try
        {
        if(isChecked== false)
        {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Switch off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Switch on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   

        }


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("switchfailed",e.toString());
    }

  }


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the OncheckedChangedListener() for the toggle button in the onCreateMethod as soon as you define it. I think you are defining the onClick for the toggle button in the XML file. You have a logical error here as in the first time the button is clicked, you are setting the listener. Hence from the next time on, it works as expected but doesn't work for just the first time. To solve this:

- set the OnCheckedChangedListener() for the toggle button within the
  onCreate() method.
- remove the onClick() definition in the XML and you
  can also get rid of the getStatus() method

To implement the OnCheckedChangedListener on a number of Toggle buttons, make your activity implement the OnCheckedChangedListener. You can then override the onCheckedChanged() method as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompundButton button, boolean isChecked) {
    if(button.getId() == R.id.toggle1) // The id for your button
        // do what you'd need for toggle1
    else if(button.getId() == R.id.toggle2)
        // do what you'd need for toggle2
    else
        // do something
}
```

You can use the above code snippet directly (but you'll have as many cases as the buttons you have). You can also use the switch statement instead. Don't forget to specify an id for all the buttons - only then can you use them.

Comment: ,Thanks for the support, It's working.Is there any alternative way to check the toggle button instead of setting OnCheckedChangedListener() in the onCreate method?? I have 50 toggle buttons in my app,i am setting the initial value as true for all the button,and i want to set the button to false when a user change it to false

Comment: What you can do is to make your activity (or Fragment wherever the view is being inflated in) implement the OnCheckedChangedListener. Then you will have to implement the onCheckedChanged method. You can use the method as show in the Edit to my answer.

Comment: See the code edit. This snippet should help you with your task